# Create/Update Subtask for a Jira Story

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, jira, jira-rest-api

I am new to Jira API & I am currently creating a google form to create a subtask automatically for any ad-hoc requests attaching to an existing story that is already created manually.

> ```
> URL: https://<subdomain>.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/<PROJECTID>
>
> STORY CREATED: PROJECTID-XXX
> ```

I have the following sample code to test:

```
function createSubTask(summary, description) {
  var URL = 'https://<subdomain>.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue';
  var username = '<user-name>';
  var password = '<api-key>';
  var userCreds = "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + password);
  var data = {
    "project": {"key": "PROJECTID"},
    "parent": {"key": "PROJECTID-XXX"},
    "summary": summary,
    "description": description,
    "issuetype": {"name":"Sub-task"}
  };
  var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
  var headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": userCreds,
    "muteHttpExceptions": "True"
  };
  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": payload
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://<subdomain>.atlassian.net returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"project":"Specify a valid project ID or key"}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

Not sure, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you please confirm the format of the value you call "PROJECTID"? In Jira, a "Project ID" will be a number such as 10200. This is DIFFERENT to the "Project Key" which will be a short string of uppercase alphanumeric characters, such as MYPROJ

Comment: the project id is in string > like `DATAP` - how can I find the project number?

Comment: My Apologies for the delay. In that case what you are using is actually the `Project Key` which is correct. Unfortunately I'm not super sure what it would be from there. The error is definitely pointing to the project being the issue though, so I suggest continuing to look there.

Answer (score 0):

```
"muteHttpExceptions": true
```

muteHttpExceptions be in the options block and true should be a bool not a string.

I was getting the `Specify a valid project ID or key` error, then swapped this in the options block and got a response error that was actually the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following payload format. It will fix the problem.

```json
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
       }
   }
}
```